# Can We Currently Import Quantum Datasets (Datasets Containing Quantum Data) Onto NISQ-era Quantum Computers?

Tags: circuit-construction, simulation, cirq, machine-learning, computational-models

I'm *still* investigating the TFQ whitepaper.

---

In one section of the paper, the authors say this with respect to Quantum Datasets

> In general, [a quantum dataset] might come from a given black-box source...
>   **However, as current quantum computers cannot import quantum data from external sources,**
>   the user has to specify quantum circuits which generate the data.
>   Quantum datasets are prepared using unparameterized **`cirq.Circuit`** objects and are
>   injected into the computational graph using **`tfq.convert_to_tensor`**

---

As I would like to investigate datasets like (QM9, QM8, etc.) and was hoping there was a way to involve **`TFQ/Cirq`**, this has raised a few questions for me.

Are there current methods for importing datasets containing Quantum Data onto a Quantum Computer? Similarly, is it possible to use **`TFQ or CIRQ`** or a similar Quantum-Computing/QML library to explore datasets like this in a way that garners a benefit from the use of Quantum Circuits and other Quantum Computer specific attributes?